# Get the data inside the column in laravel notification

Tags: arrays, laravel, pusher

Using DD in my controller i have this result. Now i want to get the **"id":45** in column name **data** 
[image]

**Controller:**

```
 public function readbyid($id){

    $test = DB::table('notifications')->where('id','=', $id)->get();

 dd($test);}
```

Comment: There is just one element in the data array, so you can pick it up with `$test['data'][0]` otherwise you can use the array_filter method from php to look up the the id https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id is unique, use `first` instead of `get`

```
 $test = DB::table('notifications')->where('id', $id)->first();
 $dataId = $test->data->id;
 //or $dataId = json_decode($test->data)->id;
```

Comment: sir im getting error ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: id

Comment: Sir jackpot it works haha  using this code dataId = json_decode($test->data)->id; thank you sir  almost 4 days i was looking ways to solve this notification hehe.

Comment: @Grace i think you need use eloquent with casts https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: i was trying to redirect the notification link to its proper post same like facbook when click the notification will redirect to the page where id=id.. without using vue.js hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Notification; 

$test = Notification::where('id', $id)->first();
$dataId = $test->id;
dd($dataId);
```